# How to apply multiple operands to a single operator?

Tags: c#, operators

How to apply multiple operands to a single operator?

An example:

instead of

```
if (foo == "dog" || foo == "cat" || foo == "human")
```

I can have the following or similar:

```
if (foo == ("dog" || "cat" || "human"));
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your first version already includes multiple operators in one expression. It sounds like you want to apply multiple *operands* ("dog", "cat", "human") to a single *operator* (`==` in this case).

For *that specific example* you could use:

```
// Note: could extract this array (or make it a set etc) and reuse the same
// collection each time we evaluate this.
if (new[] { "dog", "cat", "human" }.Contains(foo))
```

But there's no general one-size-fits-all version of this for all operators.

EDIT: As noted in comments, the above won't perform as well as the hard-coded version.

Comment: I should point out, that this will have worse performance than simply hard-coding the expression (but is likely more flexible/maintainable)

Comment: @JonSkeet: thanks. I have re-phrased my question. What I'm comparing (dog, cat,human) is an operand, then what is "foo"? Operatee?

Comment: @KMC: Okay, so the basic answer is "you can't in general, here's one specific solution for the example given".

Answer (score 1):

Can do something like this:

```
List<string> values = new List<string> {"dog", "cat", "human"}; 
values.Any(s=>s.Equals(foo ));
```

But in my opinion the code you written is already more readable then any other solution.
If we are not talking here  about of possible dozens of options, naturally.

Comment: Why use Any instead of Contains?

Comment: @JonSkeet: does it make a difference on List<T> ?

Comment: Well it's *simpler* to use `Contains`... why not use the simpler code, which also happens to be compatible with .NET 2.0?

Comment: @JonSkeet: the matter of test. I just *chose* this one in fast&fury typing...:)

Answer (score 1):

Use switch case

```
switch(foo)
{
   case "dog":
   case "cat":
   case "human":
   //Your Code
   break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always try it out, compile and see for yourself :)

```
("dog" || "cat" || "human")
```

is not a meaningful expression for C#

Maybe you can put them in an array and loop over them.

Or better still, put them in an array and come up with a cool lambda expression.